# How to turn array into string in maco?

Tags: mako

I have an object in which array with strings are stored. I have tried different ways, but it didn't work.
For example:

```
${', '.join(data.array_of_strings)}
```

Answer (score 0):

By "array of strings" do you mean a list/tuple of strings, or do mean this [array](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) of type char.  If you mean a list/tuple of strings, then the snippet you have in your question should work.  Here is a minimal working example.

## Test.py

```
from mako.template import Template
class Data(object): pass
data = Data()
data.array_of_strings = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print Template("${', '.join(data.array_of_strings)}").render(data=data)
```

Which, when executed produces the following.

```
>> python test.py
a, b, c
```